# How to dynamically link menu items to sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Using jQuery, how can I dynamically add `href` and `id` attributes to link the menu items to the sections in the code below in order?

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>nav1</a></li>
      <li><a>nav2</a></li>
      <li><a>nav3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="main-section"></section>
  <section class="main-section"></section>
  <section class="main-section"></section>
</body>
```

It should look like this after.

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#id1">nav1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#id2">nav2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#id3">nav3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="id1" class="main-section"></section>
  <section id="id2" class="main-section"></section>
  <section id="id3" class="main-section"></section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.....

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Justin_sam/zybsxca1/1/)

Html :

```
<ul>

</ul>
</nav>
<div id='addMore'>
</div>

<button id='btn'>add section and link</button>
```

Jquery :

```
var count = 0;

$('#btn').click(function(){
$('#addMore').append('<section id="id'+ count+'" class="main-section"></section>');

$('nav ul').append('<li><a href="id'+ count+'">nav'+count+'</a></li>');
count++;
});
```

let me know if it according to you requirements...

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

How about this: *First build your strings*

```
var sections ="";
var list = "<ul>";
for(var i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
   list += '<li><a href="#id'+i+'">nav'+i+'</a></li>';
   sections += '<section id="id'+i+'" class="main-section"></section>';
}
list += "</ul>"
```

*Then add them somewhere like:*

```
$('nav').html(list );
$('#container').html(sections);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution :

> adding id dynamically to section within body according to nav element

Seems like the `nav` element exist already then the solution is find the `a` element length(for creating section), then insert newly created element after existing `section` or `nav`. Hope this helped.

**Html**

```
<nav>
 <ul>
    <li><a>nav1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>nav2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>nav3</a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('nav li a').each(function(i,e){  
  var section;
  $(this).attr('href','#id'+(i+1)); 

  section = $('<section/>',{
    class : 'main-section',
    id : 'id'+(i+1)
  });
  if ( $('nav').next().is('section') ) {
     $(section).insertAfter($('nav').nextAll().last());
  } else {
    $(section).insertAfter('nav');
  }

});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/wuf0vpkc/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/kh5zk0ft/)

```
var totalLists = 4;
var listitems='';
var sectionitems='';
$(document).ready(function(){

    for(var i = 1; i<= totalLists; i++){
        listitems = listitems+'<li><a href="#id'+i+'">nav'+i+'</a></li>';
        sectionitems=sectionitems+'<section id="id'+i+'" class="main-section"></section>'
    }
    $("#navlists").append(listitems);
    $("#section").append(sectionitems);

});
```

Comment: all sections id are similar

Comment: Sorry my  mistake. <section id="id'+i+'" class="main-section"></section>. updated the code. http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/kh5zk0ft/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the links, then assign common `href` and `id` values based on the index of the link.

This checks if the section exists before setting the attributes.

```js
var sections = $('section.main-section');
$('nav a').each(function(index){ 
    if(sections.eq(index).length) {
        $(this).attr('href','#section' + index);
        sections.eq(index).attr('id','section' + index);
    }
})
```

```css
/* This CSS is for demo purposes only */                                          html, body { margin: 0; height: 100%; } .main-section { height: 100%; } ul,li { padding: 0; margin: 0; } ul { position: fixed; } li { display: inline-block; } #section0 { background: rgb(150,200,250); } #section1 { background: rgb(250,200,150); } #section2 { background: rgb(150,250,200); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a>nav1</a></li>
        <li><a>nav2</a></li>
        <li><a>nav3</a></li>
        <li><a>nav4</a></li> <!-- This will not change because 
                                  there is no fourth section -->
    </ul>
</nav>
<section class="main-section"></section>
<section class="main-section"></section>
<section class="main-section"></section>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot!  Your solution is really what I wanted.Great solution! It works very fine.Thanks again for your solution.

Comment: Your solution is easiest to understand and simple.Thanks.Buti am really sorrythat  i don't know how to mark as accepted!!!

Comment: Click on the hollow checkmark underneath the voting buttons beside this answer :) See also: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/288751)